# WebSQL doesn't work in my Android App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm developing an app using phonegap and jquery. This app can save to a WebSQL database and show the rows.
When I emulate my code on my computer it works fine (saves to the database). When I try it on my device (Android 4.2) it won't insert to the database.

When I emulate the app, I use the Ripple extension for chrome which means I do not need to include anything related to phonegap to make it work (except for phonegap.js which is only created when I build my project).
I build my project with Phonegap Build. My best guess is, that I might need to add something to config.xml or include a .js-file to include WebSQL/SQLLite when I build it?

This is how I open the database:
window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000)
Should be fine for testing, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Phonegap Devloper chat :http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Comment: Thank you for the link, however I need 20 reputation to talk in the chat.

Comment: What issue you get? Tried calling any alerts on success or failure? Can you post the code that you used?

Comment: The code I use when I insert is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/4gE63/
Works fine when I execute it with Ripple